# PDFSharp rendering tif images unwanted grey overlay

Tags: c#, transparency, tiff, pdfsharp

Rendering a TIFF image with PDFSharp in C# (WPF build) results in some sort of "grey overlay" in the PDF document - you see it in the right image:

[image: TIFF File source and resulting PDF Document view illustration]

The original source TIFF File can be found at the following download-link:

https://gofile.io/?c=Gx3AWA

The source TIFF file has no color definition inside the circle (besides the obvious circular border) and should therefore result in a perfect white being rendered inside the circle.
However after creating the PDF document there is this grey overlay inside the circle. I have no idea where this comes from - more confusingly it is only in the inside of the circle but the outside stays in perfect white.

The TIFF file is set to CMYK color mode. The PDF document itself is set to CMYK as well.
This is the relevant code I use:

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
document.Options.ColorMode = PdfColorMode.Cmyk;

PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
page.Width = XUnit.FromMillimeter((int)pageSizeX);
page.Height = XUnit.FromMillimeter((int)pageSizeY);

Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream bImgStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream([path_to_tiff_file]);
XImage bImg = XImage.FromStream(bImgStream);

XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

gfx.DrawImage( bImg, x, y, w, h );
```

The border of the circle itself is somewhat "less saturated" as well in the PDF document. So it seems that for some reason there is an overlay drawn upon the whole circle making the inside grey and weakening the circles border...

Any hints that could help me to figure this out would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The TIF file you upload seems to be corrupted?

Comment: @JMK what do you mean by "corrupted"? Can't see it...

Comment: Was getting out or memory errors running your code against it, re-saved it and working now!

Comment: can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: Actually no, the image in my PDF is the same as the TIF file. The only thing I'm doing differently is reading the file directly with *XImage bImg = XImage.FromFile("example.tiff");*

Comment: Reading from file doesn't change anything for me... So... what can I look for? I have no idea where my bug is... Are you sure it's plain perfect white in the middle of the circle in your app?

Comment: Yep, checked with the colour picker. Do you have the same issue with similar files?

Comment: well... This image is intended to be used as an overlay to create the "rounded-circle" effect. I started using PNG files - that worked perfectly. But then the document had to be in CMYK color mode. Unfortunately PNG can be either CMYK or have transparency - so I switched to TIFF (which can be CMYK with transparency). And for all the TIFF files I created in Photoshop (out of the source-PNG-files) it's the same. They all fail to be transparent in the middle...

Comment: If it helps, the file you uploaded was erroring out and wouldn't open in Paint, I had to open and re-save it in Paint 3D (no idea why?!) and then it worked, with transparency.

Comment: Could you give me a link to your version of the file?

Comment: https://www.pcloud.com/track?url=aHR0cHM6Ly90cmFuc2Zlci5wY2xvdWQuY29tL2Rvd25sb2FkLmh0bWw/Y29kZT01WmtyMkE3WnMzOTR5WVQ4dHJWWlNIQWpaME1MWGhtSjlRUzRoM1BSdzV1ZUJ4WVE0MjJxeQ==&token=j7yZZ7ZpkZrwc0kENluc4wtObKMPkdF8xn5b07

Comment: Thanks bro - but your image has no transparancy but a white background and is in RGB color mode. I need both - transparency and CMYK...

Comment: Woops, I'll have a further fiddle here!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194188/discussion-between-jmk-and-user3440145).